# How to make uwsgi use python2.7 instead of python3.5 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu, uwsgi

I need to use python2.7 for my script. I deploy using uwsgi+nginx
As the system is Ubuntu 16.04, there are two versions of python 2.7 and 3.5.

What I tried:
Created virtuenv in next way:

```
 virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 venv
```

but it gave me result:

```
New python executable in /home/user/venv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /home/user/venv/bin/python
```

As you can guess in /home/user/venv/bin/python located python3.5

I also tried in my site.ini put a version of python, my site.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
project = myproject
uid = user
base = /home/%(uid)/websites
home = %(base)/%(project)/venv
pythonpath = /home/%(uid)/websites/%(project)/venv/bin/python2.7

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/%(project)/venv
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(uid):www-data

chmod-socket = 660
```

After all actions, I still get the error:

```
Sep 10 07:59:49 ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01-sep17 uwsgi[14174]: thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Sep 10 07:59:49 ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01-sep17 uwsgi[14174]: uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/myproject.sock fd 3
Sep 10 07:59:49 ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01-sep17 uwsgi[14174]: setuid() to 1000
Sep 10 07:59:49 ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01-sep17 uwsgi[14174]: Python version: 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609
Sep 10 07:59:49 ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01-sep17 uwsgi[14174]: Set PythonHome to /home/user/websites/myproject/venv
Sep 10 07:59:49 ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01-sep17 uwsgi[14174]: Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
Sep 10 07:59:49 ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01-sep17 uwsgi[14174]: ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Sep 10 07:59:49 ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01-sep17 uwsgi[14174]: Current thread 0x00007fb0561d2700 (most recent call first):
Sep 10 07:59:49 ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01-sep17 uwsgi[14174]: Sun Sep 10 07:59:49 2017 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance myproject.ini (
Sep 10 07:59:52 ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01-sep17 uwsgi[14174]: Sun Sep 10 07:59:52 2017 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance myproject.ini
```

As you can see, it doesn't use python2.7